# In Photoshop is there a way to change the style of multiple text elements at the same time?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I have several text elements that I would like to resize at the same time, but I can only seem to select and change them one by one.  This is tough because I need to select, change, deselect, reselect, etc, which is a lot of unnecessary mouse clicking.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You should open up your "Character Styles" pane and start creating character styles.  This will allow you to 'assign' character styles to specified type on your page, then you just change your specific character style and voila:  All of them are changed.

[image]

It's a bit picky, but it's a good 30 minute learning curve.  Once you start playing around, you'll understand it quite easily.

Comment: Is this photoshop?

Comment: New in CS6 or CC I think.

Comment: Yup, I believe this started in Photoshop CS5 - You can do this in Illustrator too, and I think that started in CS3 or 4.

Answer (score 5):

Shift-click to select multiple type layers and change them all at one.

Command/Ctrl-click to select type layers which are not next to each other.